# When using NoteProperties in PowerShell .tostring() functions fail without intermediate variables

Tags: powershell, tostring

Is it not possible to expand a .tostring() in double quotes in powershell?

The following code works as expected

```
foreach($j in $i.data) {
    if (!(Get-Member -inputobject $item -name $j.attribute -Membertype Properties)) {
        $item | add-member -type NoteProperty -name $j.attribute -value $j.attribute_data
    } else {
        $after = $j.attribute.tostring()
        $item."$after" += (";" + $j.attribute_data)
    }
}
```

this fails:

```
$item."$j.attribute.tostring()" += (";" + $j.attribute_data)
```

with:

> Property 'System.Xml.XmlElement.attribute.tostring()' cannot be
>   found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. At line:9
>   char:27
>   +                     $item. <<<< "$j.attribute.tostring()" += (";" + $j.attribute_data)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: What *fails* means? Provide complete error message.

Comment: I'd pipe to `Out-Sting` instead of calling `ToString()`. In PowerShell the latter usually doesn't do what you'd think it should do.

Comment: @PetSerAl I've added the error message for the second code group. I retried the first code group and no longer got the error so it must have been a typo. I've removed the first half and rephrased the question.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht Can you provide an example of what you mean by Out-String vs .tostring()?

Comment: If you want to expand value of expression, than you should use subexpression operator `$()`. Without it only variables are expanded and anything else considered to be literal text, as you can see in error message: *'System.Xml.XmlElement.attribute.tostring()'*.

Comment: @PetSerAl so that would be $item."$($j.attribute.tostring())" then?

Comment: Yes, it should work this way, but as your string consist of single subexpression, you can omit quotes: `$item.($j.attribute.tostring())`.